# What is the definition of a Maven "request property" vs a "system property"?

Tags: maven

I'm puzzling over the meaning of the following sentence [in documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation) on the Apache Maven site: "NOTE: interpolation for this element is limited to ${basedir}, System properties and request properties."

The only [detailed definition of Maven "properties"](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) I can find on the Apache Maven site is on the same page. It mentions nothing vaguely resembling a "request property"; something called a "Java system property" is mentioned, but it's hard to tell whether it still means the same thing when you remove the word "Java".

So what do these two terms mean in the wacky world of Maven POMs?

Answer (score 0):

I assume they are referring top the user properties you pass in with -D.

Here is the API for the MavenExecutionRequest class: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest.html

They show system and [user properties](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest.html#setUserProperties%28java.util.Properties%29).